# Rewrite order resource

Tags: overrides

I am trying to rewrite:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order.php
```

However I can't find the correct resource model identifier to use in my `config.xml`

```
<models>
    <what_should_this_be>
         <rewrite> Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Sales_Order_Resource_Order</rewrite>
    </what_should_this_be>
</models>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try bellow code

```
    <global>
        <models>
            <sales_resource>
                <rewrite>
                    <order>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Sales_Order_Resource_Order</order>
                </rewrite>
            </sales_resource>
        </models>
    </global>
```